# How to put const string value in map

Tags: c++, stl

I want to create a map ,

`std::map <MESSAGE_CATEGORY, const std::string> m_mapResponseDesc;`

I am using `operator[]` to append a value in the map:

```
m_mapResponseDesc[STATUS_LIMIT] = "Limit has been exceeded";
```

`STATUS_LIMIT` is of type `enum`.

I am getting error:

> error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Please point out what mistake I have done. I am not getting any clue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `operator[]` returns a reference (to a `const std::string`) you will need to use the `insert()` method instead.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   std::map<int, const std::string> m;
   m.insert(std::make_pair(1, "Hello"));
   return 0;
}
```

***Update for C++11:***

You can do this even easier now:

```
std::map<int, const std::string> status = {
        {200, "OK"},
        {404, "Not Found"}
    };
```

Comment: I didn't much get when you say [] returns a reference. 
Any reference object = something //is possible. I am sorry if that is a very basic question.

Comment: A reference object only allows assignment if it is non-`const`, however the referenced returned from `operator[]` will be a `const std::string&`, which does not allow assignment (it results in a compiler error, the exact one that you were seeing).